# What is the best android and ios wallet for EOS?

Tags: wallet

Is there an android or ios EOS wallet developed yet? And which one is the best as of today (2018 sept)

Comment: block.one is building an ios hardware wallet, but it's not known when it will be ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally like [EOS Lynx](https://eoslynx.com/) (unsecure link) because of the user friendly UI, and a UX that I'm used to. Supports Android and IOS. They also support an array of options, such as creating an account, or importing existing keys into an account.